# What are the principles of organizing C++ code in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, code-organization

I'm a seasoned C++ developer in a new position. My experience is in *nix-based systems, and I'm working with Visual Studio for my first time.

I find that I'm constantly struggling with Visual Studio for things I consider trivial. I feel like I haven't grokked how I'm *supposed* to be using VS; so I try doing things "the way I'm used to," which takes me down a rabbit-hole of awkward workarounds, wasted time, and constant frustration. I don't need a VS 101 tutorial; what I need is some kind of conversion guide - "Here's the VS way of doing things."

That's my general question - "What's the VS way of doing things?". That might be a bit vague, so I'll describe what's giving me grief. Ideally, I'm not looking for "Here's the specific set of steps to do that specific thing," but rather "You're looking at it wrong; here's the terms and concepts you need to understand to use VS effectively."

---

In C++, I'm used to having a great measure of control over code organization and the build process. I feel like VS is working strongly against me here:

- I strongly tend to write small, isolated building blocks, and then bigger chunks that put those blocks together in different combination.

  - As a trivial example, for a given unit or project, I make a point of having strong separation between the unit's headers meant for client inclusion; the unit's actual implementation; and any testing code.
  - I'm likely to have multiple different test projects, some of which will probably rely on common testing code (beyond the code-under-test itself).
- VS makes it onerous to actually control code location. If I want a project's code to be divided into an `include/` folder and a `src/` folder, that's now a serious hassle.
- VS's concept of "projects" seems, as far as I can tell, somewhere between what I'd think of as "final build target" and "intermediate build target." As far as I can tell, basically anything I want to share between multiple projects, must *also* be a project.

  - But if many intermediate objects now become projects, then I'm suddenly finding myself with a TON of small projects.
  - And managing a ton of small projects is incredibly frustrating. They each have a million settings and definitions (under multiple configurations and platforms...) that are a real pain to transfer from one project to the other.
  - This encourages me to lump lots of unrelated code together in a single project, just to reduce the number of projects I need to manage.

---

I'm struggling with this *constantly*. I can find solutions to any one given thing, but it's clear to me that I'm missing a wider understanding of how Visual Studio, as a tool, is *meant* to be used. Call it correct workflow, or correct project organization - any solutions or advice would be a real help to me.

(**Note:** much as I'd like to, "Stop working with the Visual Studio buildchain" is not an option at the moment.)

Comment: "I find that I'm constantly struggling with Visual Studio for things I consider trivial." After fifteen years, I believe I can say that those feelings never go away.

Comment: what ide did you use before?

Comment: "VS makes it onerous to actually control code location. If I want a project's code to be divided into an include/ folder and a src/ folder, that's now a serious hassle." Where, exactly, is the hassle? That's how *all* of my code is divided, all edited from Visual Studio. As far as code-sharing, create a static library. You'll need a project for it, but you won't need to include that project in all of your solutions.

Comment: I have switched to [CMake](http://www.cmake.org) generating "NMake Makefiles". Development done via Vim (as it should be), compilation done via (n)make (as it should be -- the MSVC compiler, but run from the command line), no more headaches. Check [JAWS](http://jaws.rootdirectory.de) for an example setup that does much more than "just that".

Comment: I mitigated this frustration by using CMake. A significant advantage with CMake is that it makes it much easier to migrate projects to new versions of Visual Studio. The number of files to maintain is drastically diminished, and settings are easier to change since they are clearly exposed in .txt files.

Comment: @tobi303: Eclipse, mostly. Different Make-base build systems.

Comment: @CodyGray: VS doesn't let me control the location of a file I create (unless I create it outside VS, then add it to the project), or move files around, or even show me the directory structure. Again-- I might just be missing how to find this functionality.

Comment: Generally creating projects is something you do once and very rarely change.  The last smallish (2 million lines of code) solution I worked on had >130 projects and we had dependencies on more solutions which were pulled in as dll.  I reality some of those projects should of been farmed out to their own solutions and consumed, but while development wasn't 'active' there were occasional tweaking and fixing going on.  You may be adding a flurry of projects at the start but that settles down fairly rapidly.

Comment: @CodyGray: re: static libraries - Sure, but I don't want ONE static shared resource. I have a bunch of them, for different purposes, that don't really belong together. so now that's a BUNCH of static-lib projects (instead of a bunch of plain compiled objects).

Comment: As for the file locations: Generally you shouldn't need to worry, unless you are planning to release this as a source library to be consumed.

Comment: @graham.reeds : Fair enough, but shouldn't that be a choice *I* can make, somehow?

Comment: A single static library will work fine. You can put everything in there and let the linker remove anything that is not used by the project. Or, just go ahead and create multiple projects. Working with them should not be a problem. If it's performance you're worried about, you can unload them from within the IDE (right-click -> Unload Project).

Comment: @CodyGray : I know it'll *work*. I can get things working! :) But I also want things well-organized; I want clear separation between unrelated components; I want it fairly clear what segments of the code are being used by the higher-level components. One static-library as a general purpose dumping ground is something I'd rather avoid if possible.

Comment: VS is opinionated. I found it easier to go with the flow than swim against the tide. Again you spend more time editing files than creating/moving them.

Comment: I agree my suggestion isn't a particularly good one. Honestly, it's weird reading all of these comments. I suspect that you're onto something in thinking that you just aren't "thinking" the right way when it comes to using Visual Studio. I use it for all of my C++ development and hardly ever feel like I'm fighting against the organizational structure that it imposes on me. Problem is, I don't really understand enough about the differences between the way that we work to translate.

Comment: @CodyGray: I think what I'm most looking for is an explanation of what, exactly, "projects" and "solutions" are meant to represent, and the basic tools for managing their organization and relationship. Even just major terms would be helpful, because I might be entirely missing something basic that I've been working around.

Comment: @CodyGray: Maybe this would be a better question for chat? Would you care to chat for a little while, and maybe that'd work better? If you've got the time :)
(---aaaaand then I clicked on your profile. "Sorry, I don't do chat!" Don't blame you :P)

Comment: @Ziv A solution is a group of projects that work together to solve a problem ("I need a Paint application", for instance). In many cases a solution includes a number of DLLs and an EXE (each is a project). The problem you have, we all have with new things. There is no substitute for experience. If you do not want to read a book, use MSDN.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments and help. I can see that the question is probably overly broad. I've taken another stab at narrowing down one specific issue I'm having, at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35293595/avoiding-dependencies-is-exploding-the-number-of-projects-in-my-vs-solution ; maybe that one will be more answerable and start setting me on the right path. Thank you all :)

Answer (score 1):

The basic rule is: A project results in a single output file [1].

If you want to package building blocks into static libraries, create a project for each one.

Unit test are separate from the code, so it's common to see a "foo" and a "foo test" project side by side.

With respect to your small building blocks, I use this guideline: If it is closely enough related to be put in the same folder, it is closely enough related to be put in the same project.

> And managing a ton of small projects is incredibly frustrating. They each have a million settings and definitions (under multiple configurations and platforms...) that are a real pain to transfer from one project to the other.

**Property pages** are intended to solve this problem. Just define a property page containing related settings and definitions, and it becomes as easy as adding the property page to a new project.

As each project can pull its settings from multiple property pages, you can group them into logical groups. As an example: a "unit test" property page with all settings related to your unit test framework.

To create property page in Visual Studio 2015: in the View menu, there is an option "Property Manager". You get a different tree view of your solution, with the projects, then the configurations, and then all the property pages for that project+configuration combination. The context menu for the configuration has an option to create a new property page or to add an existing one.

---

[1] Although it is common to have the Release configuration result in foo.dll and Debug configuration in food.dll, so they can exist next to each other without resorting to the Debug/ and Release/ folders. In the General properties, set the TargetName to "$(ProjectName)d" (for Debug configuration) and remove the "$(Configuration)" from the OutputDirectory (for all configurations) to achieve this.